# How can I read a process' standard output in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I need to execute a nodeJS script in the groovy like below

```
"./npm install".execute()
def x = "npm run docker-deploy".execute()
```

but i need in my nodeJS script return a value, in this case i want to return the deployInfo variable, there must be a way to return or share this variable in the node to groovy?

```
'use strict';

const nodeReleaseTasks = require('./docker-deployOld');

const pkg = require('../package.json');

var deployInfo = "";

function getDeployInfo(deployResponse) {
    deployInfo = deployResponse;
}

nodeReleaseTasks({
    name: pkg.name,
    version: pkg.version
}, pkg.name, getDeployInfo);
```

Comment: what does `nodeReleaseTasks` do?

Should it return a value? Does it output anything to `stdout`? Is it supposed to? If not node can do nothing with it.

Comment: nodeReleaseTask only call a callback

Comment: module.exports = function(projectProperties, deploymentName, callback) {
 let teste = "test";
 callback(teste);
};